# get response of browser after open webpage swift

Tags: swift

Hi I open one url in my app

```
 UIApplication.shared.open(webURL! as URL, options: [:])
```

I want when finished work in browser I get response , and get last URL of webpage
how to do that?
swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below code in your `viewDidLoad`.

```
let webView = UIWebView()

webView.scalesPageToFit = true
webView.delegate = self
view.addSubview(webView)
webView.fillOnSupperView()
webView.delegate = self

let request = URLRequest(url:  
URL(string:"https://www.google.com"))
webView.loadRequest(request) // load your url here
```

Comment: Please note that `UIWebView` will be deprecated in iOS 12, so you should be moving to `WKWebView` moving forwards. Also, what is `fillOnSupperView()`?